# Info messages after editing crontab

Tags: rhel, cron

This should hopefully be a simple question, but I couldn't find the right search term in Google to show me what I was after...

This morning I went to look at my crontab to remind myself of the location of a running script;

```
crontab -e
```

I found the location, and then exited <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

I was then shown a message

```
[1]+ Stopped
```

**What does this mean?** I've never seen this message before.

Normally I'd expect the message *"no changes made to crontab"* or if I'd made edits *"installing new crontab"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output is from the [bash job control system](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php). It is telling you that the first job (`[1]`) and the last process to be backgrounded (`+`) has been `Stopped` (aka paused/suspended). If you run the command `jobs` it will print currently backgrounded/suspended processes you will likely see your command listed.

One way to stop (suspend) processes like this is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, which is likely what you did by accident when trying to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The process has not ended, and is not likely to have saved your changes. To resume the command in the foreground so you can actually save and quit run `fg`.

Comment: Perfect thanks, must have been an accidental `Ctrl` key press. Everything matches up with what you've described.